# Firebase getIdToken function is not being executed for some strange reason

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, mern

I am using firebasefor authentication in my react app which also have a server side.
I used the official documenation of firebase to create an Id token.But for some strange reason the function is not getting executed! not even showing any error!
here is the function I amtalking about:

```
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        // ...
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(idToken);
        sessionStorage.setItem('token',idToken);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
    // sessionStorage.setItem("token", idToken);
    // console.log(idToken);
  };
```

And here is the full code of that part:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebase.config";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { UserContext } from "../../App";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router";
// import { useLocation,Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
// const firebaseConfig = {
//   // ...
// };

// // Initialize Firebase
// const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// // Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
// const auth = getAuth(app);

const Login = () => {
  const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useContext(UserContext);
  //  const navigate =useNavigate();
  //  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

  //  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }

  const handleGoogleSignI = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);

        const token = credential.accessToken;
        const idToken= credential.idToken;
        // console.log("credential: ",id_token);
        // The signed-in user info.
        const { displayName, email } = result.user;
        const signedinuser = { name: displayName, email };
        setLoggedInUser(signedinuser);
        // console.log(token);
        // storeAuthToken();
        storeAuthToken();
        // navigate(from, { replace: true })
        history.replace(from);
        // console.log(user);
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        // const email = error.customData.email;
        const email = error.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
      });
  };
  const storeAuthToken = () => {
     console.log("i am called");
    // firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
    //   // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
    //   // ...
    //   console.log("hello");
    //   console.log(idToken);
    //   sessionStorage.setItem('token',idToken);
    // }).catch(function(error) {
    //   // Handle error
    //   console.log(error);
    // });
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        // ...
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(idToken);
        sessionStorage.setItem('token',idToken);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
    // sessionStorage.setItem("token", idToken);
    // console.log(idToken);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is Login</h1>
      <button onClick={handleGoogleSignI}>Google Sign in</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I tried to create an Id token but nothing happened even though i followed the official documntation.